# How do developing sequels work? When's a good time to develop one?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I recently got an option to develop sequels:

[image: Develop Sequel]

When's a good time to develop a sequel? What are the advantages and disadvantages of developing a sequel to a previous game? What factors should I consider when choosing a previous game to develop a sequel of?

Comment: I've developed a sequel to a game that had a rating of 9.0 and the sequel flopped. On the other hand, I've made a sequel to a game that was rated ~5.5 and it scored 9.75. I have no idea how this works, so +1. However, I do know that using a new game engine in a sequel gives it a rating boost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, it does not matter much if you take a flop game to make a sequel of or one of your acclaimed games. The sequel can be a success or a flop, no matter the previous game.

However, what I noticed is that if you make a sequel to a previously successful game, you generate more hype, which can affect final sale figures. So a bad sequel to a previously successful game can potentially generate more money than a mediocre sequel to a previously bad title. If your sequel goes viral, there is no real difference anymore.

Be careful not to develop sequels too fast. One time I was making a sequel once the previous game was out and after making a new engine. 
Critics told me that it is just a blatant money grab and gave me 3-5's despite having cutting edge technology in the engine.

To make a final list:

- Develop sequels not too fast after the first game was released
- Making a sequel to a previously good game generates more hype
- A sequel to a bad game can still be successful.